# Is not only gcc itself installation enough to build c language in my windows machine?

Tags: c, gcc, cygwin, installation, environment

I'm not sure what the meaning of installing a compiler(say, gcc) is.

I have an windows machine and will install cygwin.
cygwin has many packages and i installed gcc-related-packages.
But wait, gcc is just a compiler and is not including header files such as stdio.h, stdlib.h, etc. 
What compiler does is just finding a header file specified in a some source file.

Installing compiler means (implicitly) installing related header files?

Comment: gcc package that cygwin installs includes all the files required for building.
 [Read this](http://matpack.de/cygwin/).

Answer (score 0):

The Cygwin installer knows about package dependencies, and installing `gcc` will pull in the minimum set of packages needed to compile C programs.  However, if you need particular libraries beyond the basic C library, you will have to install them separately.